# How can I periodically verify if Mariadb master and slave nodes are out-of-sync in a kubernetes environment?

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, cluster-computing

We have a Mariadb cluster in kubernetes environment. But due to some issues master and slave nodes often go out of sync and the applications are getting impacted due to this.

Is there any best way to periodically verify if these nodes are not in sync, to notify the system administrators about this. If verification could be initiated by a java program

Do not know what options to try

Answer (score 0):

The [healtcheck.sh](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/healthcheck.sh) script as part of the Docker Official Image MariaDB container can help with this:

The environment variables take effect on creation only to make a `mysql@localhost` user with the right grants. The [mariadb-operator](https://github.com/mariadb-operator/mariadb-operator/) can be used to also create the same [user](https://github.com/mariadb-operator/mariadb-operator/blob/main/examples/manifests/mariadb_v1alpha1_user.yaml) and [grant](https://github.com/mariadb-operator/mariadb-operator/blob/main/examples/manifests/mariadb_v1alpha1_grant.yaml).

And then the `healthcheck` script executed as a [liveness tests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) like:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: mariadb:lts
    env:
    - name: MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER
      value: 1
    - name: MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_GRANTS
      values: "REPLICA MONITOR"
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - healthcheck.sh
        - --su-mysql
        - --replication_io
        - --replication_sql
        - --replication_seconds_behind_master=10
        - --replication
```

"10" is the seconds behind master.

Comment: Is there any way to make write/read to land at master node only?

Comment: sometimes django etc frameworks that facilitate multiple connections, or alternately something like sqlproxy / maxscale.